# zelda a link between worlds maiamai - On section 2

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I can't seem to find the Maiamai on section 2 of the map. If you segment the map with the colored sections, I can't seem to find the one in section 2. Has anyone found that one yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to which one you are referring so [here  is the full list.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-between-worlds/Maiamai_Locations)

[Also an interactive map](http://www.ign.com/maps/the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-between-worlds/overworld?filter=maimai)

[And list of video guides by areas](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Zelda:%20A%20Link%20Between%20Worlds%20-%20%20Maiamai%20&sm=3)

Comment: Thx for the links, helps a bunch!